# Access ViewBag from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I'm passing some value from the controller to the view with ViewBag, I am trying to access this value from JavaScript like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
     var val = '@(ViewBag.Lon)';
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val;
    }
</script>

<h3 id="demo" >Passing Data From Controller to View using ViewBag</h3>
```

Where Lon is propery of type int.

but when I run this code it doest shows the value I'm passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor code can be added with Javascript
    var x=JSON.Parse(@ViewBag.objJson...)

Comment: what console of browser say?

Comment: DrawPath:42 Uncaught TypeError: JSON.Parse is not a function
    at window.onload (MyPage:42)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var val = JSON.Parse(@ViewBag.Lon)
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val;
    }
</script>

<h3 id="demo">Passing Data From Controller to View using ViewBag</h3>

Comment: `JSON.parse(..)` exactly

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've had a similar issue before and for a statistical table 
so try using the code below I'm sure it will work. 
var val = @html.Raw(ViewBag.Lon);

Comment: You can also use JavaScriptSerializer in C# and covert C# object to JSon and pars it within the the same way @html.Raw(Serialized JSON);